# Copy n lines from one CSV and paste them n times in another CSV

Tags: linux, join, awk, sed

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to figure this one out.

I have two CSV files, one of them without headers and the other with headers.

```
file1.csv (no headers):
apples
bananas

file2.csv (with headers):
HEADER1,HEADER2
item1,item3
item1,item3
item1,item3
item2,item3
item2,item3
item2,item3
```

I would like to create a new file: "file3.csv" where "apples" and "bananas" are listed the same number of times as "item1" and "item2" respectively.

The resulting file3.csv should look like this:

```
file3.csv
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3
item1,item3,apples
item1,item3,apples
item1,item3,apples
item2,item3,bananas
item2,item3,bananas
item2,item3,bananas
```

To add the new header I'm using `echo "$(head -n 1 file2.csv),HEADER3 >file3.csv`.

To copy and paste the lines I've tried to do it with: `awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1; next} {print $0,a[$1]}' file1.csv file2.csv` but it doesn't work as I intend.

If an awk expert could help me a little, I would be eternally thankful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

golfed version

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[NR+1]=$1;a[1]="HEADER3";next} $3=a[b[$1]=c+=!b[$1]]' file{1,2}.csv

HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3
item1,item3,apples
item1,item3,apples
item1,item3,apples
item2,item3,bananas
item2,item3,bananas
item2,item3,bananas
```

Comment: @codingnewby do you understand what `$3=a[b[$1]=c+=!b[$1]]` does? Do you understand that when its result is `0` nothing will be printed and understand what, if anything, can cause that to happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == FNR {
    idx2fruit[FNR] = $0
    next
}
!seen[$1]++ {
    item2idx[$1] = cnt++
}
{
    idx = item2idx[$1]
    fruit = (FNR > 1 ? idx2fruit[idx] : "HEADER3")
    print $0, fruit
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.csv file2.csv
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3
item1,item3,apples
item1,item3,apples
item1,item3,apples
item2,item3,bananas
item2,item3,bananas
item2,item3,bananas
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/cat file1/e;s/$/\n/;x;s/$/,HEADER3/;b}
        2H;:a;G;/^([^,]*,).*\n\1/{s/\n([^\n]*).*/,\1/;b}
        x;s/^[^\n]*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/;x;s/\n.*//;H;ba' file2
```

Overview:

Keep `file1` lines in the hold space and append them to lines from `file2`. When the key changes in `file2` pop off a line from `file1` in the hold space and repeat.

N.B. The hold space doubles as a repository for lines from `file1` and also stores the previous lines key from `file2`.

Prime the hold space with records from `file1` and append the third header.

Compare the current line with the previous and if the keys are the same, append the first line in the hold space of `file1`

Otherwise, delete the first line in the hold space of `file1` and replace the key by the current lines key, remove the appended lines from the hold space on the the current line, then jump back and execute the previous instructions as to when the keys matched.